# CREATE SCHEMA in Redshift fails to create a schema

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I've created a new database, `customer_test`, in Redshift on the same cluster where most of my data lives (in the `dev` database). I've created this database using a superuser.

My problem arises when I run `create schema new_schema` in the new database. The query runs fine, and when I query `PG_NAMESPACE` I see the schema there. I can even create tables. But if I disconnect and reconnect, the schema is gone. I don't see any specification in the RS documentation that schemas are temporary, and I've verified this is a superuser. Is there a reason my created schemas are disappearing? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you commit your changes?

Comment: Oddly enough, yes. I did an explicit `commit;` after for a check and it still failed

Comment: Did you try to `SET SCHEMA` or `SET search_path to schema`? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-schemas.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same and faced the same issue. I created a table and inserted rows inside the table after which it was persistent.